# EC scheme for one-way encryption

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves

Consider this scenario:

Alice and Bob need to share some secret messages. Alice is the sender and Bob is the receiver.  This should be facilitated by Bob giving Alice a public key, such as in a certificate provided through a URL on a trusted site. The communication is one-way; Bob does not need to send any encrypted messages to Alice.
Preferrably, Elliptic Curve cryptography should be used.
Additionally, the size of the encrypted messages is likely small, such as < 32 bytes.
The messages are unpredictable random numbers (basically keys themselves, so in essence this is all about securely sharing a secret among two parties).

Initially I thought of implementing a standard ECDH scheme, but this seems unnecessary when Bob never needs to send anything to Alice, so to ask Bob to maintain a keypair and certificate seems excessive.

Second I thought of using ephemeral AES keys to encrypt the secret messages, and then encrypt the AES key with the public EC key, and then simply decide on a format for passing the encrypted ephemeral key, the IV and the encrypted message from Alice to Bob. I've done this in the past, but with RSA instead of EC.

Is there a go-to scheme for this scenario? EC is typically mentioned only in signature and key agreement use-cases it seems. Is it unsuitable to use EC for encryption of ephemeral AES keys? If reasonable, which AES and EC schemes would be suitable?

Furthermore, provided the data is small (<32 bytes), would directly encrypting the secret messages themselves with the public EC key be wise? Of course, if the size of messages would grow in the future, this would break, but assuming it doesn't? I'm guessing this approach could be dangerous if messages were predicatable (such as every communication starting out with a known HELLO message, hence giving an attacker access to plain text and cipher text pairs),
but assuming the messages themselves are random and never really repeated, is there any security risk using EC to directly encrypt the payloads?

Or is there a completely different approach which is preferrable here?

Comment: How Bob if going to know that he is speaking with Alice?

Comment: That's taken care out out of band. This is part of a web API where authenticated clients store data through REST endpoints, and for one particular endpoint, the data being stored needs to be encrypted on a second layer. So we have both TLS and a JWT based authentication scheme to ensure trust.

Comment: Also why not static-ephemeral ECDH? https://noiseprotocol.org/ has secure ways to implement that. ECC isn't useful for encryption. Just like RSA isn't useful for encrypting anything other than symmetric keys, really.

Comment: The reason for the second layer of encryption is perhaps out of scope of the question, but it has to do with the fact that secret messages need to be exported from one system, then carried over an insecure environment, and then imported into the client which then uses the REST API to upload it.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus I know assymetric crypto is useful mostly for signing and as KEKs, but the data being encrypted is in practice a key albeit from an external source, and is small enough to not really require an AES layer.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus But yes, I guess I could in fact use static-ephemeral ECDH in a single one-way message if Alice creates an ephemeral key pair, derives a shared secret from her ephemeral SK + Bob's static PK and sends the ephemeral PK to Bob immediately followed by the payload encrypted by the shared secret key.